# How to synchronize multiple mail (thunderbird) accounts?

Tags: server, thunderbird, multiple-workstations

I was wondering if the following setup is possible using Ubuntu (server) and Ubuntu (workstation):

I have two workstations with Thunderbird as mail client
I have one server

On both workstations I want the mail to be synchronized so when I write an email it will appear in the "sent" folder of the second computer too.
Also when I am not near my workstation and login to the server (remote) I want to be able to write an email with the same result as above.

I figured out that I need to install Thunderbird on both workstations and on the server, then I need to link the mail file to all 3 clients. The question is "How do I do that?"

Perhaps this question is answered before, in that case I am sorry for asking again.

With kind regards,
Marchel.

-EDIT-
I found this on MozillaZine:
Install Thunderbird separately on each computer but store your profile on a portable USB device or on a network file share. To launch Thunderbird with that profile, use the -profile "path" command line argument.

Is it just straightforward installing or is there something I need to beware of?

(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Have you tried IMAP?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and best solution is configuring all your email clients to use [IMAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol), if your mail service supports it.

If IMAP isn't supported by your email service, you have a few options:

1. Store your Thunderbird profile in Ubuntu One.
2. Store your Thunderbird profile on the server, and share it via SSHFS/CIFS/NFS. It's usually desirably to do this as part of a more general [SSO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SingleSignOn) solution.
3. Synchronize the Thunderbird profiles with a file sync utility such as [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/).

Comment: IMAP could be a solution but has the same functionality as the web interface of my ISP. I want to be able to use the same layout (signature etc) from wherever I am. That's why I thought about installing Thunderbird client on a server which I can logon to from any location.

Answer (score 0):

you can also store the profiles folder

```
/home/<user>/.thunderbird/<cryptic>
```

into your dropbox and enter the location in the profiles.ini.
Make sure u set isRelative to 0 if you use an absolute path.

Works for years for me now on many many machines. =)